# Obtaining ticks from system boot in Windows Store app

Tags: time, windows-store-apps

[PointerPoint.Timestamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.pointerpoint.timestamp.aspx) property contains time relative to the system boot time, in microseconds. I am looking for a way to get *current time* in compatible format. Also time from system boot will be a more efficient way to work with time intervals than `DateTime.Now`.

Window API has functions like `GetTickCount` and `GetTickCount64`, but they are unavailable for a Windows Phone.  Is there something similar for a Windows Store App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [System.Environment.TickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.